# Use texdoc within a shell script (in Alfred.app) doesn’t work

Tags: documentation, texdoc

I’m trying to call textoc from OS X Application [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/) as a shell script.

[image: alfred window]

And with Alfred everything seems fine—I already asked the developers but they say that the script should work. When debugging I get the message

```
21.9.11 17:14:12
[0x0-0x40040].com.alfredapp.Alfred[977]
env: texlua: No such file or directory
```

therefore I guess it’s a problem with `texdoc` and not with Alfred.
I get the same error if I call `texdoc` with an apple script

```
do shell script "texdoc file"
```

But when calling `texdoc file` directly in my Terminal or in not-silent mode of Alfred (which means a terminal window opens and the command is executed) everything works.
A shell script (td.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
texdoc $1
```

called with `sh td.sh file` works too.

Hope that anyone has an idea how to solve this or at least point where I can get help …

Comment: I guess that the default shell doesn't know about the correct path to the binaries. On my system, `osascript -e 'do shell script "texdoc amsmath"'` does what's expected. What's the answer to `osascript -e 'do shell script "echo $PATH"'` given to the terminal?

Comment: @egreg: Mille grazie! That leads me to the solution. If you post your text as an answer I’d upvote and accept it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite strange, with MacTeX, that the default shell, which is called when a shell script is executed via AppleScript, doesn't have `/opt/texbin/` in the PATH variable.

It depends on the version of Mac OS X you're running. On Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6, there should be a file called `TeX` in `/etc/paths.d/`, containing just the line

```
/usr/texbin
```

If it's not there, then something has gone wrong with your installation of MacTeX. It's quite easy to correct the behavior: do the following from a terminal window

```
echo /usr/texbin > TeX
sudo mv TeX /etc/paths.d
```

and a logoff-login cycle should bring the system into shape. However I don't have a 10.7 machine available, so if your system version is this one, wait for comments.

Check also that a file TeX is present also in `/etc/manpaths.d/`; if not,

```
echo /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Man > TeX
sudo mv TeX /etc/manpaths.d
```

is needed in order to access to the `man` pages for the TeX programs.

Comment: I got both files. My TeX system works fine I guess, but `texdoc` is only available form Alfred if I add the `PATH` to the script. And in TeXmakerx I need to write `"/usr/texbin/latex"` instead of `latex` to make it work. But then everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Tobi gave an answer with an [Alfred v1 extension](http://www.tobias-weh.de/download/alfred-td.zip); however, extensions are no longer supported with the [v2 release](http://blog.alfredapp.com/post/2013/03/14/alfred-v2-is-here), which now uses "workflows." I created a [workflow for `texdoc`](https://github.com/spl/texdoc-alfred-workflow) using the information on this page.

The critical part of the workflow (which is really simple) is the Bash script, which uses egreg's answer to determine the TeX path:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:`cat /etc/paths.d/TeX`
texdoc {query}
```

This script works with (at least) TeX Live 2013.

**Edit**: Updated to reflect that Tobi removed his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I updated the workflow on my computer but forget about this question. You may like to include my icon in your’s?! Send me an email (mail@tweh.de) and I’ll send you the icon files …