# TeX Live directory structure

Tags: amsmath, texlive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX, package documentation look-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62653/latex-package-documentation-look-up)

This information must be somewhere on the Internet, but I am not able to Google it ...  I am using `amsmath` with TeX Live (Ubuntu in case that is relevant). Specifically I want to use `amsart`. I know there comes sample documents with the installation, which (together with other documentation) must live somewhere in the huge directory tree TeX Live is using. I have been looking under `/usr/share`, but cannot find anything pertaining to `amsmath` (nor to other installed package for that matter!) Where are they living? And where on the Internet is such information?

Comment: `texdoc amsart` should show you the documentation, to see where the files were installed do `kpsewhich amsart.cls`

Comment: As per David Carlisle's comment: On my system the file is at `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls`.