# Finding package documentation

Tags: packages, tutorials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX, package documentation look-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62653/latex-package-documentation-look-up)

Where can I find the documentation for `\usepackage{float}`? And in general how do I find package documentations? Usually, I google `usepackage{<package>}` and hope that the documentation will show up.

Comment: At `www.texdoc.net` :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar, perhaps move your comment to an answer?

Comment: Are you interested in documentation for `\usepackage` or for the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float). Document to the latter is available from [CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf).

Comment: I do `locate float | grep doc`.

Comment: `texdoc float` should do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First source (as I like it now) is at [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/)

Second source is to use `texdoc` from command prompt:

```
texdoc float
```

Syntax: `texdoc <package name>`

Third, if you are using an editor like WinEdt goto: `Help -> LaTeX doc` and type the package name. (This basically uses `texdoc` itself).  Or just double click on `\usepackage` as noted by Holle.

And last, but not least is to type: `http://ctan.org/pkg/<packagename>` in your browser window to directly go to CTAN.

Comment: If you use WinEdt just double-click the `\usepackage`.