# Unknown operator x or x^{2}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texmaker

I am trying to generate the following pgfplot:

### Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x}, 
    ylabel={y}, 
    grid, 
    ticks=none
]
\addplot[blue, no marks, smooth, domain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5x -y};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it throws an error multiple times:

```
 ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or `x^' (in '25-5x^{2} -y^{2}').
See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.19 ...omain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5x^{2} -y^{2}};
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

In my messages/Log section, there are about 70x of the above error.

The Function that I want to Plot:
[image: function]

Function details:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `5*x`, not `5x`. You can't omit the multiplication operator in `pgfmath`. So you can write your equation as `25-5*x*x-y*y`. (Do not mix `pgfmath` expressions and LaTeX math language, they're completely different beasts.)

Comment: +1 Thank you...

Comment: @Rmano another error:`! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
pected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with
[samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.
See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.19 ...h, domain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5*x*x-y*y};
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can't omit the multiplication operation `*` in `pgfmath` expressions (this is not a LaTeX math formula!).

Secondly, you should always use a `compat` level with `pgfplots`, otherwise the behavior will be buggy (you have the following warning:

```
 Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble.
```

Finally, you are drawing a 3d-plot, so you need to use `addplot3` (or similar functions, see the manual).

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x}, 
    ylabel={y}, 
    grid, 
    ticks=none
]
\addplot3[blue, no marks, smooth, domain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5*x*x -y*y};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the nice aliasing pattern due to the mesh...  probably you want `surf` instead of `smooth` here. See manual at pages 124 and following:
https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfplots/0#section.4.6

Comment: wonderful I got the function. But I  have some questions. First, your section 4.6 link does not work. Alternative link? Secondly, what manual do i need to read?

Comment: Works perfectly here. Anyway, you can go to `texdoc.net`, and given that you are using `pgfplots`,  you should look for `pgfplots` manual. Just type `pgfplots`  in the text area and choose the first link below (the small eye icon). 
Anyway, you probably have all the documentation locally available --- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380019/how-to-find-the-documentation-for-a-package

Comment: will this work on miktex CLI? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380019/how-to-find-the-documentation-for-a-package#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20to,texdoc%20pgf

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but you can see it as a starting point:

[image: pgfplots]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {
            Z(\x,\y) = 25 - \x^2 - \y^2;
        }]
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x}, 
    ylabel={y}, 
    grid, 
    ticks=none,
    view={100}{20}, 
    enlargelimits,
    domain=0:5,
    samples=50, 
    restrict z to domain=0:30
    ]
\addplot3[surf] {Z(x,y)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you explain the things after `\begin{axis}`?

Comment: The `view` is to let you view your shape from the desired point of view (delete it to see the effect). The `restrict z` is to only view the deisred part of the shape on the z axis (if you delete it, you will have more underneath).

Comment: Ok. other attributes?

Comment: I think that everything is pretty straightforward and you could learn from the code by commenting some lines and see what happens. Once again, I'm not that into pgfplots so the design is not perfect and could probably be improved.

Comment: yeah. i can do that!!!

Comment: An way, I got the function correct but I have a another question can you look a bit?https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606638/how-to-find-the-x-value-and-the-y-value-in-a-point-in-a-pgfplot