# How to find the x value and the y value in a point in a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to know the `x` value and the `y` value on a pgfplot area to draw a line. How to find it?

For an example, I need to draw a line from the X label to the Y label; to do so I need to get the `x` value and the `y` value of the labels to fill the `\pslineoptions` thing.

I am using Texmaker + Miktex.

### screenshot of the texmaker window

[image: My workspace screen hot]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x}, 
    ylabel={y}, 
    grid, 
    ticks=none
]
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5*x*x -y*y};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post only a screenshot as a MWE. No one has the time to re-write the entire code to test it. Please edit your post by adding your complete MWE.

Comment: @SebGlav well it is not about coding, it is about the interface/interacting in texmaker.

Comment: @SebGlav There is no need to do coding to answer my question, I am asking a **way** finding the `x value and y value`

Comment: @SebGlav anyway, i am going to edit the question...

Comment: What do you mean by `x value` and `y value`? In wich coordinate system? If you need a line, why don't you draw it directly in the graph ? (`\draw` and all Ti*k*Z commands work in `pgfplots`)

Comment: by `x value and y value` I meant the position in the document.

Comment: >If you need a line, why don't you draw it directly in the graph ? (\draw and all TikZ >commands work in pgfplots) **How?**

Comment: You might find \whereami interesting.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168452/how-can-i-draw-a-3d-three-sided-5-7-9-triangle-with-tikz-or-pstricks/168482?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.4680#168482

Comment: @John thanks I plan to read pgfplots and TikZ documentation tommorow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal Ti*k*Z commands in `pgfplots`; the only problem is to identify which coordinate system you want and avoid clipping if you need it.

In the case of 3d graphs, the relevant part is around page 359 of the manual. You have to take care of precedence yourself to avoid the line above the graph, if needed...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    grid,
    ticks=none,
    % clip mode=individual,
]

\draw [thick, blue] (rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:0.5,1,0);
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=10] {25-5*x*x -y*y};
\draw [thick, red] (rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0.5,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PD notice that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is default since 2018 and not needed, but you probably want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`...

Comment: You are a precious stone!!! thank you. Thanks. You couldn't find a way to get the x value and the y value of the labels or some point?

Comment: how to customize the `(rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:0.5,1,0)` in the `\draw` thing to get my own positions?

Comment: So... `\draw` worls like in css; first line = loaded first, Am I correct?

Comment: It's quite complex (no idea of CSS myself). I suggest you take the first tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual (I know, it's a 1000+ pages manual, but hey...)

Comment: what i said is that first `\draw` prints first second `\draw` prints second. Am I correct?

Comment: how to customize the `(rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:0.5,1,0)` in the `\draw` thing to get my own positions?

Comment: @Gomesz785 CSS= _Cascading Style Sheets_. cs= _coordinate system_.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "my own position". And yes, `\draw`, `\addplot`, `\node` etc are executed in the order they appear.

Comment: @Paul No I am not Talking about ABRs. sorry.

Comment: @Rmano you finally got it!