# How to draw a line, a curved line and an arc on a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, draw, line

I have written the following code.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\author{Some dude's name}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    xlabel={x}, 
    ylabel={y}, 
    grid, 
    ticks=30
]
\draw [thick, blue] (rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:0.5,1,0);
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=50] {25-5*x*x -y*y};
\draw [thick, red] (rel axis cs:0.5,0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0.5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Current outout + my texmaker window

[image: scrnsht]

### what I need(edited with MS paint, Purple colour = a line, a curved line and a arc)

[image]

One can notice the Red and the blue `\draw` near addplot 3.

I want to erase it(delete that lines) and draw a line, a curved line and a arc like above

Comment: Well, to erase those, just remove the lines I suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606645/38080. Then find the coordinate you want (in the graph x,y,z coordinate system) and just draw them using Ti*k*Z command. If the curved line is just a line in the surface, you can use a 3d line graph (another addplot with a null y-domain).

Comment: @Rmano can you give me relevant page numbers for to do above things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do --- then you can add things and change the coordinates (you will need to calculate where do you want your lines to go, exactly). I heavily commented the code to give you a lot of "fish lines" to catch your own fish.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    % explicitly specify axis limits
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=18,zmax=26,
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    grid,
    % do not clip the \draw commands and clip each
    % addplot to its domain
    clip mode=individual,
]
% line on the xy plane (that way goes behind the surface)
% we mark a point at 30% of the line
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,1,18) coordinate[pos=0.3](a);
% main surface
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=10] {25-5*x*x -y*y};
% graph restricted at at y=0.3 (parametric curve format)
\addplot3[ultra thick, no marks, domain=0:1, samples=10, samples y=1] (x, 0.3, 25-5*x*x -0.3*0.3);
% line  touching the parabola
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,0.3,25-5*0.4*0.4-0.3*0.3) coordinate[pos=0.3](b);% coordinate on the black parabola
% draw spline and angle label
% in and out are the angle at which the curve leaves the final and initial point
\draw[thick,->] (a) to[out=100, in=-10]  node[midway, above right]{$\alpha$} (b);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You maybe prefer to have the surface semi-transparent, to better convey the meaning of the arc:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    % explicitly specify axis limits
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=18,zmax=26,
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    grid,
    % do not clip the \draw commands and clip each
    % addplot to its domain
    clip mode=individual,
]
% line on the xy plane (that way goes behind the surface)
% we mark a point at 30% of the line
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,1,18) coordinate[pos=0.3](a);
% line  touching the parabola
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,0.3,25-5*0.4*0.4-0.3*0.3) coordinate[pos=0.3](b);% coordinate on the black parabola
% main surface, semi-transparent
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=10, opacity=0.7] {25-5*x*x -y*y};
% graph restricted at at y=0.3 (parametric curve format)
\addplot3[ultra thick, no marks, domain=0:1, samples=10, samples y=1] (x, 0.3, 25-5*x*x -0.3*0.3);
% draw spline and angle label
% in and out are the angle at which the curve leaves the final and initial point
\draw[thick,->] (a) to[out=100, in=-10]  node[midway, above right]{$\alpha$} (b);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Best. I feel like we are communicting brain-to-brain.

Comment: ;-) if you did post this question straight on it would have been much faster... I think this is a clear example of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: did you mean to ask the series of problems I asked today as a one? or improve the structure of the this question?

Comment: I thought that the series of problem where just an attempt to obtain this graph. If you just posted the original graph with the added lines with MSPaint, I could have posted this answer directly ;-). No harm done, really.

Comment: No harm done for me or you?

Comment: sorry. I will post in the future like that.

Comment: No harm for neither! ;-)

Comment: yeah I think the series way is kinda timeconsuming :)

Comment: checkout:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606689/what-does-coordinatepos-0-3-do-in-a-draw-command