# What does coordinate[pos=0.3] do in a \draw command?

Tags: pgfplots, draw

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    % explicitly specify axis limits
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=18,zmax=26,
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    grid,
    % do not clip the \draw commands and clip each
    % addplot to its domain
    clip mode=individual,
]
% line on the xy plane (that way goes behind the surface)
% we mark a point at 30% of the line
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,1,18) coordinate[pos=0.3](a);
% line  touching the parabola
\draw[thick]  (0.4,0,18) -- (0.4,0.3,25-5*0.4*0.4-0.3*0.3) coordinate[pos=0.3](b);% coordinate on the black parabola
% main surface, semi-transparent
\addplot3[blue, no marks, surf, domain=0:1, samples=10, opacity=0.9] {25-5*x*x -y*y};
% graph restricted at at y=0.3 (parametric curve format)
\addplot3[ultra thick, no marks, domain=0:1, samples=10, samples y=1] (x, 0.3, 25-5*x*x -0.3*0.3);
% draw spline and angle label
% in and out are the angle at which the curve leaves the final and initial point
\draw[thick,->] (a) to[out=100, in=-10]  node[midway, above right]{$\alpha$} (b);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What does `coordinate[pos=0.3]` do in a `\draw` command? like does it have to do with somekind of panning in the graph?

Another question:

Tell me a wonderful way to put `pgfplot` examples in the public domain. I am thinking a GitHub repository such as APEXCalculus. Do any of you have a good idea?

Comment: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html https://texample.net/ ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a personal advice, you should really go through the tutorials in [the Ti*k*z manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz/0), especially the first one; otherwise you will spend *much* more time with this kind of doubts. `pgfplots` is based on Ti*k*Z, and as you need basic arithmetic to understand algebra, so you should learn Ti*k*Z to use `pgfplots` or other libraries based on it.

Anyway

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
```

draws a line from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` in the current coordinate system.

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) coordinate(A);
```

gives a name to the coordinate `(1,1)` that you can reuse (so that for example, you can change coordinates in a drawing in just one place).

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) coordinate[pos=0.3145](B);
```

gives a name to the coordinate in the segment from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` at the position `0.3145` (where `0` corresponds to `(0,0)` and `1` to `(1,1)`).

Example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) coordinate(A);
    \draw (0,-2) -- (1,-1) coordinate[pos=0.3](B);
    \draw [red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might've been mad at me for not accepting your detailed answer or even comment. My appologies. What happened was this: My computer temporarly broke; went to the otther computer; then got a site/login error. (the error - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409433/i-have-connected-my-stack-overflow-account-to-tex-se-and-meta-se-cant-login-wi) _Yikes!_ Now I am on my primary computor!!! **YAY**. So your answer is great, just pure platinum. **I will reply after reading the answer**