# enumitem - alignment of multiline labels in description environment

Tags: enumitem

I am trying to make my multiline labels aligned to the right. I applied `style=multiline` and `align=right` options to enumitem description environment. Here's the code describing the issues:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% multiline, left-aligned
\begin{description}[style=multiline, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm]
    \item[Truth-functional\\ connective] A sentence connective with the property that the truth value of the newly formed sentence is determined solely by the truth value(s) of the constituent sentence(s), nothing more.
\end{description}

% multiline, right-aligned; the option is not applied.
\begin{description}[align=right, style=multiline, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm]
    \item[Truth-functional connective] A sentence connective with the property that the truth value of the newly formed sentence is determined solely by the truth value(s) of the constituent sentence(s), nothing more.
\end{description}

% the order of options changed; different result.
\begin{description}[style=multiline, align=right, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm]
    \item[Truth-functional connective] A sentence connective with the property that the truth value of the newly formed sentence is determined solely by the truth value(s) of the constituent sentence(s), nothing more.
\end{description}

% The label aligned as intended with a single line label.
\begin{description}[align=right, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm]
    \item[Truth-functional] A sentence connective with the property that the truth value of the newly formed sentence is determined solely by the truth value(s) of the constituent sentence(s), nothing more.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a single-line label, there's no problem. But the options do not work correctly with a multiline label. Only the first and the last ones worked as intended. What's happening inside this code?

The desired output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's analyze, what's going on in your examples. For this, note that, as explained in `enumitem`'s documentation, `multiline` is equivalent to `style=standard,align=parleft,labelwidth=!`.

1. `style=multiline, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm`

   This is working as intended: A fixed-width label with automatic line breaking. It is left-aligned due to `parleft`.
2. `align=right, style=multiline, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm`

   This is exactly the same thing, as `style=multiline` sets `align=parleft`, which overwrites the previous setting.
3. `style=multiline, align=right, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm`

   Setting `align=right` effectively undoes the central part of `style=multiline` (i.e. the part that creates the `\parbox`). I'm not sure why, but this leads to an `Infinite glue shrinkage` error when I run your example. Are you not getting this error? In theory, I would have expected this to be identical to the next case.
4. `align=right, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm`

   Here again you get what you expect: Right alignment, but no `\parbox`.

---

So how do we get what you want? The most straight-forward option is to just create a new alignment `parright` that does the same thing as `parleft` but with right alignment. We can just copy the definition from page 6 of the documentation and replace `\raggedright` with `\raggedleft`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft#1}}}

\begin{document}

% multiline, left-aligned
\begin{description}[align=parright, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm]
    \item[Truth-functional connective] A sentence connective with the property that the truth value of the newly formed sentence is determined solely by the truth value(s) of the constituent sentence(s), nothing more.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you but I am a bit frustrated. How could I know all these things if you were not there?

Comment: @Hermis14 Sometimes with TeX and friends considerable expertise is required to understand or solve a problem, which is only acquired through studying the subject extensively (i.e. you need to read a lot and gather experience). In this particular case, however, all of the necessary information was readily available in `enumitem`'s documentation. (In fact, I did not know any of this three hours ago.) You can find it [on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) or on your computer using `texdoc enumitem` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380075/48973)).