# What are the preset numbered lists available in enumitem?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumitem

I use `enumitem` lists all the time for unnumbered lists, bulleted lists, checkboxes, etc, and I know that `[label=\arabic*]` changes the default numbering to give me `regular' numbers.  What I would like to know is: what are all of the options for numbered lists?  (meaning, the alternatives to `\arabic*`?) I can't find a list of the available preset numbering schema.  (Also, if I wanted to create my own ordered numberlist, how would I do it?)

Comment: Do you mean `\alph`, `\Alph`, `\arabic`, `\roman` and `\Roman`? More complex examples are in the friendly manual.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I am looking for. Could you point me to this friendly manual?  My google skills are failing me.

Comment: On finding documentation more reliably, see [How to find the documentation for a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380019/2693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways in which you can format your numbered lists. In addition to arabic, there are also roman numbers (`\roman` and `\Roman`) and letters (`\alph` and `\Alph`). The manual has many more complex examples (e.g. combining various types, etc.)

Documentation should come standard with your LaTeX distribution. That said, there's always CTAN, the [**C**omprehensive **T**eX **A**rchive **N**etwork](https://www.ctan.org/). In your case: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf