# Function of "Elements" without Backslash in Command-Definitions

Tags: macros, documentation, definition, renewcommand

I have a general question which I couldn't solve so far. It came up a few days ago, while I was trying to redefine the different parts of the footer of the [`scrlayer-scrpage` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687594/how-to-find-macros-to-adjust-footer-lefoot-cefoot-etc-with-scrlayer-scrpage) (this still isn't solved for me).

But i want to understand it in general. So far, I've read a lot of (basic) documentation (source2e, scrlayer-scrpage.dtx etc.) and still couldn't figure it out:

In some command/environment-definitons there appear "elements" which have no backslash at the start of the name. For example the elements `even`, `left` and `foot` in the definition of the `\lefoot` command from `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
$ latexdef -p scrlayer-scrpage -f lefoot
\lefoot first defined in "scrlayer-scrpage.sty".

\lefoot:
macro:->\sls@renewelement {even}{left}{foot}
```

or the element `labelitem` (inside the curly brackets, first word) in the general definition of the `itemize` environment:

```latex
$ latexdef -f itemize
\itemize is defined by (La)TeX.

\itemize:
macro:->\ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@ \@toodeep \else \advance \@itemdepth \@ne 
\edef \@itemitem {labelitem\romannumeral \the \@itemdepth }\expandafter \list 
\csname \@itemitem \endcsname {\def \makelabel ##1{\hss \llap {##1}}}\fi
```

How can i find out what they mean/how they are defined? So far, i have no real clue.

I'm aware that the answer may be really simple, but right now I am at a loss...

Thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `labelitem` in `\itemize` is literally just a string of characters. From `latex.ltx` you find

```
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
```

The line `\edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}` sets the macro `\@itemitem` to take the value of the string `labelitem` followed by the lowercase Roman numeral representation of the current "depth" of the list. So if have a nested list and the second level is an `itemize`, you have `\@itemdepth` is equal to 2, in which case the line becomes `\edef\@itemitem{labelitemii}`. In other words, the macro `\@itemitem` is defined to be the string `labelitemii`.

Now this by itself is not that useful, but if you scan down a couple lines, you find that it issues `\csname\@itemitem\endcsname` which expands to `\csname labelitemii\endcsname` in our example, which is equivalent to calling `\labelitemii` (that's the purpose of `\csname ... \endcsname`).

This is an example of how you can build *variable names* programmatically in TeX (in many other programming languages something similar would perhaps be handled by using an "array" or a "dictionary", which concepts are absent in TeX).

---

The `\sls@renewelement{even}{left}{foot}` functions similarly; basically it makes `\lefoot{SOMETHING}` equal to `\sls@renewelement{even}{left}{foot}{SOMETHING}`, and the definition of `\sls@renewelement{A}{B}{C}{SOMETHING}` builds an internal variable/macro whose name incorporates the strings `A`, `B`, and `C` (more precisely, in the case of `\lefoot` you get a macro named `\sls@ps@scrheadings@even@left@foot`) and sets it equal to `SOMETHING`.

Comment: Hi @Willie thanks for the explanation. It makes absolutely sense that expanding `\@itemitem` inside the `\csname` command results in `\labelitemii`. Latex is just so different from other programming languages... The `foot` thing also makes some sense, but i still don't fully understand how the standard layout of the commands `\lefoot`, `\cefoot` and `\refoot` are defined (e.g. as centered `\mbox` or something else) and where to find it. There has to be one. E.g. if i use the package without edits the pagenumber appears at the outside of the footer (which should be `\rofoot` or `\lefoot`).

Comment: But the second part belongs more to my [particular question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687594/how-to-find-macros-to-adjust-footer-lefoot-cefoot-etc-with-scrlayer-scrpage) concerning the footer. I don't want to hijack my own question ;)

Comment: The commands `\lefoot` etc are just wrappers for commands to _re_define the pagestyle. Each of `scrreprt.cls`, `scrartcl.cls`, and `scrbook.cls` sets the footers using direct calls to those `\<loc>foot` commands; for example, they all have somewhere `\cfoot[\pagemark]{}` to have the page number appear centered in the footer.

Comment: So to find out where the `scrlayer-scrpage` package sets the "defaults", you need to look for where those commands are called, and not where they are defined. For example, if your load the package not from one of the KOMA document classes, it will default to the `standard` page style; looking at where `\sls@ps@style@standard` is defined, you see that it calls `\ohead{\pagemark}` and `\cfoot[\if@twoside\else\pagemark\fi]{}`. Note that these just says what goes where; the actual formatting is done by whatever sets `\pagemark`.