# Does the package mathrsfs have a documentation?

Tags: fonts

I try to read documentations to have more ease with what I am writing with, is there a documentation for the package called `mathrsfs` ?
Thanks

Comment: I think the readme https://mirror.funkfreundelandshut.de/latex/macros/latex/contrib/jknappen/mathrsfs.rme is the closest thing one gets to a documentation....

Answer (score 1):

The file `mathrsfs.sty` is not exactly wordy:

```
%% mathrsfs.sty
%%
%% (c) Copyleft 1995, 1996 J"org Knappen
%% Licence: GNU licence version 2
%% Please read the file mathrsfs.rme first
%%
\ProvidesPackage{mathrsfs}[1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)]
\DeclareSymbolFont{rsfs}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{rsfs}
\endinput
```

Typing `texdoc rsfs` at a command prompt generates the following output:

> RSFS - Ralph Smith's Formal Script Symbol Fonts
>
> Version 1.0,  Released October 1991
>
> This package contains METAFONT sources for fonts of uppercase
> script letters for use as symbols in scientific and mathematical
> typesetting.  For example, script D, N, and S are often used in
> functional analysis for domain, nullspace, and Schwartz class.
> Script L and H are the standard symbols for lagrangian and
> hamiltonian densities in quantum field theory.  These formal
> script symbols may be contrasted with informal scripts such
> as the one designed by H. Zapf and used as `calligraphic'
> symbols in the TeX math symbol font.
>
> I have tried to be fairly conservative, and closely imitated
> a formal script type designed by R. Hunter Middleton.  This is
> similar to Typo Script and Marina, as well as the font used
> by the typesetters at Springer Verlag.  All are based on the
> so-called Spencerian or Copperplate hand lettering which
> prevailed in the eighteenth century.
>
> These programs were not designed with much `meta-ness' in mind.
> Although formal script is subject to many stylistic variations,
> radical changes in weight or slant violate my sense of taste.
> This is a first revision, and certainly does not reflect much
> expertise in METAFONT programming. It has been checked for
> legibility and spacing.
>
> I have tested these fonts on some 300dpi printers (ink-jet and laser),
> but not at other resolutions.  I suspect they won't look very good at
> low resolution (because of the instrinsic detail).  Comments from users
> of the fonts are welcome; please describe your printer and metafont
> parameters when relevant.  I will probably revise the sources and hope
> to add lowercase letters to make a text font.
>
> You are welcome to use and distribute these files; if you modify them,
> please change the name but give credit to the original author!
>
> Ralph Smith, Physics 0319, Univ. of California -- San Diego
>
> 9500 Gilman Drive, La Jolla CA 92093-0319
>
> E-mail: rasmith@ucsd.edu

I suppose it's useful to have some background knowledge of "formal scripts" in general and of "Spencerian or Copperplate hand lettering which prevailed in the eighteenth century" in particular. :-)

Comment: it does? in texlive 2023 I get `$ texdoc mathrsfs
Unfortunately, there are no good matches for "mathrsfs".

Here are the top three matches:
    1 latex/jknapltx/README.TEXLIVE
    2 latex/jknapltx/00readme.txt
    3 <empty>

There may be online documentation available for "mathrsfs" at
    https://texdoc.org/serve/mathrsfs/0
This documentation may be for a different version than you have installed.

Enter number of file to view, Y to search online, or any other key to exit:`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Good catch! I should have written `texdoc rsfs` instead of `texdoc mathrsfs`. (I have no idea how I managed to stumble on `texdoc rsfs`...)  I'll fix this right away.

Comment: shouldn't we get texdoc updated so your original answer is right and my original comment is wrong?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - How about if both `texdoc rsfs` and `texdoc mathrsfs` generated the same output? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's right there on CTAN.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs

Click "Package readme".

```
mathrsfs.rme

Readme File for the mathrsfs package by J"org Knappen
(c) Copyleft 1995, 1996, 1998, 1999 J"org Knappen
Licence: GNU public licence version 2

   Physicists don't like the appearance of the standard calligraphic fonts
when speaking about Lagrangian density, Hamiltonian density, or the measure 
in the path integral. Fortunately, the Ralph Smith Formal Script (rsfs) 
fonts provide the desired shapes. The mathrsfs package makes them accesible
via the command \mathscr{ABC}.

   To use this package, just write
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
in the preamble of the document.

   If you don't have the rsfs fonts ready, get the METAFONT sources from 
the nearest CTAN archive in directory tex-archive/fonts/rsfs. There are also
PS Type 1 versions by Tako Hoekwater on CTAN.

  This package contains 3 files, namely
  mathrsfs.rme    This readme file
  mathrsfs.sty    Package file
  ursfs.fd        Font definition file
The latter two files need to be in the search path of LaTeX2e.

  This package differs from Vadim V. Zhytnikov's calrsfs package in
several aspects. It does not overwrite the \mathcal command, so that you
have the calligraphic shape still available. I also choose to do some 
internal things in a different way.

J"org Knappen, Barbarossaring 43, D-55118 Mainz, Allemagne
Author of the Book: Schnell ans Ziel mit LaTeX2e, Oldenbourg-Verlag
M"unchen, 1997, ISBN 3-486-24199-0.

Change history:

1998/03/24    Added setting of the skewchar to ursfs.fd

/mathrsfs.rme
```

Comment: In particular, this is point 4 in [tikz pgf - How to find the documentation for a package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380019/how-to-find-the-documentation-for-a-package) .